# Perl split() Function Not Handling Pipe Character Saved As A Variable

Tags: perl, csv

I'm running into a little trouble with Perl's built-in split function. I'm creating a script that edits the first line of a CSV file which uses a pipe for column delimitation. Below is the first line:

```
KEY|H1|H2|H3
```

However, when I run the script, here is the output I receive:

```
Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|Col5|Col6|Col7|Col8|Col9|Col10|Col11|Col12|Col13|
```

I have a feeling that Perl doesn't like the fact that I use a variable to actually do the split, and in this case, the variable is a pipe. When I replace the variable with an actual pipe, it works perfectly as intended. How could I go about splitting the line properly when using pipe delimitation, even when passing in a variable? Also, as a silly caveat, I don't have permissions to install an external module from CPAN, so I have to stick with built-in functions and modules.

For context, here is the necessary part of my script:

```
our $opt_h;
our $opt_f;
our $opt_d;

# Get user input - filename and delimiter
getopts("f:d:h");

if (defined($opt_h)) {
    &print_help;
    exit 0;
}

if (!defined($opt_f)) {
   $opt_f = &promptUser("Enter the Source file, for example /qa/data/testdata/prod.csv");
}

if (!defined($opt_d)) {
    $opt_d = "\|";
}

my $delimiter = "\|";
my $temp_file = $opt_f;
my @temp_file = split(/\./, $temp_file);
$temp_file = $temp_file[0]."_add-headers.".$temp_file[1];

open(source_file, "<", $opt_f) or die "Err opening $opt_f: $!";
open(temp_file, ">", $temp_file) or die "Error opening $temp_file: $!";

my $source_header = <source_file>;
my @source_header_columns = split(/${delimiter}/, $source_header);
chomp(@source_header_columns);

for (my $i=1; $i<=scalar(@source_header_columns); $i++) {
    print temp_file "Col$i";
    print temp_file "$delimiter";
}
print temp_file "\n";
while (my $line = <source_file>) {
    print temp_file "$line";
}

close(source_file);
close(temp_file);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the `|` isn't special inside doublequotes. Setting $delimiter to just `"|"` and then making sure it is quoted later would work or possibly setting $delimiter to `"\\|"` would be ok by itself.

Second, the `|` is special inside regex so you want to quote it there. The safest way to do that is ask perl to quote your code for you. Use the `\Q...\E` construct within the regex to mark out data you want quoted.

```
my @source_header_columns = split(/\Q${delimiter}\E/, $source_header);
```

### see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Comment: The doublequotes eat the `\|` and change it to just `|`. You need a pair of backslashes so that the doublequotes treat the backslashes as special and convert them to a single backslash. Your head will spin the day you have multiple characters in a regex to quote and good luck if one of them needs quoting already. Best to let perl do it for you at the regex stage.

Comment: or use `qr`. `$re = qr/\|/; split $re`

Answer (score 6):

The first argument to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a compiled regular expression or a regular expression pattern. If you want to split on *text* `|`. You'll need to pass a *pattern* that matches `|`.

[`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) creates a pattern from a string that matches that string.

```
my $delimiter = '|';
my $delimiter_pat = quotemeta($delimiter);
split $delimiter_pat
```

Alternatively, `quotemeta` can be accessed as `\Q..\E` inside double-quoted strings and the like.

```
my $delimiter = '|';
split /\Q$delimiter\E/
```

The `\E` can even be omitted if it's at the end.

```
my $delimiter = '|';
split /\Q$delimiter/
```

I mentioned that `split` also accepts a compiled regular expression.

```
my $delimiter = '|';
my $delimiter_re = qr/\Q$delimiter/;
split $delimiter_re
```

If you don't mind hardcoding the regular expression, that's the same as

```
my $delimiter_re = qr/\|/;
split $delimiter_re
```

Comment: O rly? I didn't know about the quotemeta function! I'll be sure to remember to use that from now on. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

It seems as all you want to do is count the fields in the header, and print the header. Might I suggest something a bit simpler than using split?

```
my $str="KEY|H1|H2|H3"; 
my $count=0; 
$str =~ s/\w+/"Col" . ++$count/eg; 
print "$str\n";
```

Works with most any delimeter (except alphanumeric and underscore), it also saves the number of fields in `$count`, in case you need it later.

Here's another version. This one uses the character class brackets instead, to specify "any character but this", which is just another way of defining a delimeter. You can specify delimeter from the command-line. You can use your getopts as well, but I just used a simple `shift`.

```
my $d = shift || '[^|]';
if ( $d !~ /^\[/ ) {
    $d = '[^' . $d . ']';
}
my $str="KEY|H1|H2|H3"; 
my $count=0; 
$str =~ s/$d+/"Col" . ++$count/eg; 
print "$str\n";
```

By using the brackets, you do not need to worry about escaping metacharacters.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work in my case, simply because the headers can be anything. While my example was an oversimplification, real world usage will include alphanumerics and underscores. I appreciate your reply, though, and will definitely keep this in mind!

Comment: @Zach In the second example, you may enter any character as the delimiter. It will pull out `[^X]`, if X is the delimiter you specify. Like it says, by using a character class, you do not need to worry about escaping meta characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
use strict;
my $delimeter="\\|";
my $string="A|B|C|DD|E";
my @arr=split(/$delimeter/,$string);
print Dumper(@arr)."\n";
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = 'A';
$VAR2 = 'B';
$VAR3 = 'C';
$VAR4 = 'DD';
$VAR5 = 'E';
```

seems you need define delimeter as \\|